# Compatibility issues with 2013 excel spread sheet and 2010 excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba program in excel in my computer (which is using 64bit). My friend can't have all the functions to work (hers is 32bit). What code can I add to make it compatible with the 32bit?

I want to share this excel sheet with many coworkers, so I need it to be compatible with 32bit.

I notice the error happens when calling the function in the `worksheet_SelectionChange`. I have a code that uses the Days() function.

```
 m = Application.WorksheetFunction.Days(Date, myRange)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered that perhaps the bitness had nothing to do with it, and might be that the Excel version was more relevant? AFAICT there is no `Days` worksheet function in Excel 2010, so the solution is either to use functions that exist in Excel 2010, or to upgrade everyone to the same version of Excel.

Comment: Mat, that may me the answer... my friend is using excel 2010. thanks a lot

Comment: According to [MS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DAYS-function-57740535-d549-4395-8728-0f07bff0b9df), *Days()* really not there pre-2013. Use [DATEDIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c) instead.